# Which operating system uses the lowest amount of system ressources?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I'm using a program that is calculating things as it receives information and I need it to be running on multiple virtual machines on my PC at the same time.

Now before I was going to set this up, I was wondering which operating system would be ideal to be running on the virtual machines to run as many of them as possible on restricted ressources? The only requirement is that my program is not able to run on Linux.

I was thinking of going back to Windows XP on each virtual machine, assuming the newer operating systems are taking too much ressources for themselves, but that's just a guess.

Hope someone has more knowledge than me about this and can help me out. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **NEVER** going to take these VMs online XP is a better choice. Windows 8.1 (as well as 10) is a recent design and hence is designed for high powered modern hardware, XP was designed long ago for old slower hardware. Running an older OS on newer hardware will allow it to compartively quick, certainly much faster than a new OS on old hardware. Another matter is what programs you will run, if it is old programs they will be compatible with XP, if it is new ones there is a chance XP will not be able to run them. If you are going to take these VMs online then XP is a bad idea, wonderful an operating system as it was it is now becoming insecure due microsoft stopping producing updates to patch holes in it, And do not forget also that Microsoft wouldn't support XP anymore (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help), so you should go back to the drawing table and fix your priorities and needs and then decide , cheers !

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot run *NIX / BSD Systems you can  use WFL windows xp for legacy computers it works on 128 mb RAM

Update: i386 old systems.